# How do I interpolate over tif file image using itk?

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, interpolation, itk

This only goes out to those who knows the itk package well.
I just started using itk package recently to try to play with images using it, and I have a question.

I have two tif image files(dicom images), and I want to divide the image into 4, then combine two images into one(two images have same pixels and dimensions, and they are supposed to be on top of each other).

Can anyone give me a sample code for this using itk?
Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any example code handy, but I wonder if this isn't what you are looking for:
http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1BinaryFunctorImageFilter.html#_details

Hope that helps -

Answer (score 0):

There are many well organized coding examples at:

http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples

Everything you wish to accomplish is described on those pages.